# MS SQL 2008R2 - Monthly statistic

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I´m working with **MS SQL Server 2008**, and I´d like make some stastistic every **week** / **month** for users who are connecting to this server (how many times the were connected, which table was most popular or when was the traffic most, etc...). 

I cannot find anything about this weekly / monthly statistic for SQL users.

I´ll be glad if someone can help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for general table access statistics, the `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` view is a great place to start. For every table and index in the database that's been accessed, there will be a row in that view with stats on the number of times it was seeked, scanned, or used as a lookup, and when the last access time was. You could set up a sql agent job to run every few minutes, taking a snapshot of this entire view, and then graph the results over time to show the rate at which each table/index in the database changes.

I did a quite write-up on that view a while ago at http://trycatchfinally.net/2010/01/finding-unused-tables-in-sql-server-2005-and-2008/, but it's pretty powerful - though the example I use helps identify indexes or tables that aren't being used, you could flip it around to show which ones are being used most often.

Answer (score 0):

you can create job for Monthy Period That Execute Bellow Command
    Exec Sp_UpdateStats